# How to customize a URL on tumblr

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tumblr

I am creating a tumblr account and would like to add a link to my twitter on the profile description (I am talking about the "preview" of the profile, not the themed part of it)
You can't put links directly as they are not clickable, but navigating through the profiles I have found one person that has it like this: "@username" and when you click the username it directs you to the profile.
I can't figure out a way to do it, would you please help me?

Thanks in advance
[IN THIS IMAGE YOU CAN SEE THAT THE BLUE TEXTS ARE ACTUALLY LINKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVmzc.jpg)